# Regex: All strings that finishes with .ts and does not have the word index.ts and test.ts

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

I'm using karma for testing my angular 6 app.

In my `test.ts` I have the following code:

```
context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts/);
```

Has you can see, I want to this regex is finding getting all files that has .spec.ts.

What I want is all files that finishes with .ts and does not have the word index.ts and test.ts, so I could exclude the files "index.ts" and "test.ts" from the context.

Comment: Do the files names in question end with `.spec.ts`? Why not  `/\.spec\.ts$/` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
/^(?!.*(?:index|test)).*\.ts$/
```

It uses negative look ahead to exclude `'index'` and `'test'`. Then it matches any number of any char until it finds `.'ts'`.

**Edit** according to @doom87er's comment (I misread the requirement):

```
 /^(?!.*(?:index|test)\.ts).*\.ts$/
```

Comment: changing lookahead to `(?!.*(?:index|test)\.ts)` should fix it